# How to add a new tab to a Salesforce app page on package install

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I am currently building a Salesforce app wanted to know if it is possible to add a new Visualforce page tab to the Marketing custom app when the package is installed. Something like the below image,

[image]

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: You mean the Marketing custom app is not in your namespace but something that just already existed in the target org?

Comment: @Folkert yes that right